# Why is my app downloaded on an iphone sometimes "not available anymore" after some time?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swiftui, deployment

When I download my app from xcode via usb cable on my iphone it works, but sometimes (after a day for example) it just gives the error "app nicht mehr verfügbar" (I'm in Germany, translated that is "app not available anymore"). I do not see any logic as to when or whether at all the error occurs.
From that moment on I can't get the app running again, unless I download it again.

The app has the Settings bundle, and when the app does not work anymore the settings part (for the app in the "general" settings app) still works.

Shutting down the iphone and starting again does not help.

Comment: It is something new Apple has done, if it is an Xcode app it only stays available for a few days. I haven't tested DEBUG vs RELEASE

Comment: I'm not really a fan of propitiatory systems, so forgive me the heresy: did you really download the app? Is it on your phone? Was it there at any time? Or does it just depend to connect to some apple service that is no longer supported?

Comment: @ Gyro Gearloose I run the app from xcode (clicking on the triangle) having elected my device (my iphone) instead of a simulator. The app is than what I call downloaded on the iphone and runs even after removing the usb cable.

Comment: @lorem ipsum Is "DEBUG" the way I download? You have answered my question than probably already satisfactory, because I probably will not get the error when I RELEASE the app in the Appstore, which I was afraid of.

Comment: Go to Edit Schema you can change DEBUG and RELEASE. I have a paid account and this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free Developer accounts limits the period that an app can run on real devices to 7 days (due to Provisioning Profiles)

This limitation extends to 1 year for paid accounts.

All of this limitations are for local signing (through the Xcode or other methods) and there is no verified limitation for apps that installed through the AppStore.

Unfortunately, These are poorly documented by Apple and not listed in [Apple Developer pages](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)